# How can I remove array from end singly using setState?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get rid of elements in an array using `pop()`
So i tried like this:

```
function Test() {


const [nu, setnu] = useState([]);
  const delet = () => {
    nu.pop();
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setnu([...nu, "add"])}></button>
      <button onClick={delet}>delete nu</button>
      <h1>
        {nu.map(d => (
          <>{d},</>
        ))}{" "}
      </h1>
      }
```

but for some reason elements didn't get disappeared until I click `add button`

Comment: Because you dont set the State in your "delete" method. The view will not render again when the state did not update.

Comment: Would u mind how i set the State??

Comment: The delete is just mutating state, so you don't get a proper state update/rerender until you add another value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't mutate state as you do with `nu.pop()`. Instead, shallow copy the state and then update it. Here, you can use filter function as it will generate a new array:

```
  const delet = () => {
    setnu(nu => nu.filter((n,index) => index !== nu.length-1 /* or any other condition */));
  };
```

As @DrewReese suggested, a more efficient way:

```
  const delet = () => {
    setnu(nu => nu.slice(0,-1));
  };
```

#### If you want to use pop()

```
const delet = () => {
  const copyOfNu = [...nu]
  copyOfNu.pop()
  setnu(copyOfNu)
}
```

Both does the same thing, it modifies a copied version of the state variable. When you call the setState function, react knows the state variable has changed

Comment: No problem, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-react-js) might be worth reading :)

Comment: `setnu(nu => nu.slice(0, -1));` to remove the last item (*well, rather copy all but the last element*) and return a new array. 

Comment: @DrewReese yet again, a better way. I will include it in the answer, and I thought slice was returning the sliced element. I guess mixed it with splice :D

Comment: Yeah... ...slice ...splice ...who names these things?